# Failed to start Docker Service because the control process exited with error code

Tags: docker, exit-code

I'm trying to install docker on my virtual machine:

- Update the apt package index and install Docker

  `$sudo apt update`

  `$sudo apt install docker.io -y`
- Add current user to the docker group:

  `$sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}`

  `$su - ${USER}`
- Check whether you can access and download images from Docker Hub

  `$docker run hello-world`

When I start docker, I get this error

```
liaomei@liaomei-virtualbox:~$ systemctl start docker
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

This is `systemctl status docker` output

```
liaomei@liaomei-virtualbox:~$ systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-11-08 09:15:06 +07; 3h 25min ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 26449 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, stat>
   Main PID: 26449 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Thg 11 08 09:15:03 liaomei-virtualbox systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Thg 11 08 09:15:03 liaomei-virtualbox systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Thg 11 08 09:15:03 liaomei-virtualbox systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Thg 11 08 09:15:06 liaomei-virtualbox systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Thg 11 08 09:15:06 liaomei-virtualbox systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Thg 11 08 09:15:06 liaomei-virtualbox systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Thg 11 08 09:15:06 liaomei-virtualbox systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Thg 11 08 09:15:06 liaomei-virtualbox systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

This is `journalctl -xe` output

```
liaomei@liaomei-virtualbox:~$ journalctl -xe
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Automatic restarting of the unit docker.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Thg 11 08 12:41:02 liaomei-virtualbox systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit docker.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit docker.service has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 2298 and the job result is done.
Thg 11 08 12:41:02 liaomei-virtualbox systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Thg 11 08 12:41:02 liaomei-virtualbox systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit docker.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Thg 11 08 12:41:02 liaomei-virtualbox systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: A start job for unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit docker.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 2298 and the job result is failed.
Thg 11 08 12:41:02 liaomei-virtualbox systemd[1]: docker.socket: Failed with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit docker.socket has entered the 'failed' state with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
```

This is my machine info

```
liaomei@liaomei-virtualbox:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
liaomei@liaomei-virtualbox:~$ uname -r
5.15.0-rc7+
liaomei@liaomei-virtualbox:~$ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: liaomei-virtualbox
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: 65805268c46b491797a9463a127e30ba
           Boot ID: 6d9543a77b884bea97da01da1f690e74
    Virtualization: oracle
  Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-rc7+
      Architecture: x86-64
```

I can't find the actual error in these output. Could you tell me where the problem is and how to fix it.